# explanation of Hybrid systems?

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals, theory, digital-to-analog

I want to study Detailed explanation of hybrid systems?Which incorporate both continuous and discrete time signals & systems?
for example
In which a continuous-time input signal is transformed into a discrete-time output signal and vice versa. An analog to digital (A=D) converter is an example of a hybrid system.
Where can i find detailed explanation to quench my curiosity/thirst of this topic , i have tried searching google but no useful result

Comment: No information on A/D converters on google? Maybe you have to specify more clearly what exactly you're interested in.

Comment: I am not interested in any special example/case(e.g analog to digital ). I was looking for generic explanation for this topic . I was looking general for traits of this category by which i may be able to identify systems of this type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not interested in specific practical aspects of A/D conversion, but if you want to learn basic theory concerning sampling and digital (discrete-time) processing of analog (continuous-time) signals, I'd recommend that you read and study the chapter *Sampling of Continuous-Time Signals* in Oppenheim en Schafer's book *Discrete-Time Signal Processing*.